# How can I insert an image on click in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm new to JavaScript and I have a list and when that list item is clicked, I want an image to appear, and only when it's clicked. How can I go about doing this through my JS document? I went ahead and made an ID for one of my list documents that I can use for my JS.

```html
<div class="tab-pane active full" id="status" role="tabpanel">
  <ul class="item-list">
    <li><a id="pipboy_gun_img" href="#" class="44_pistol">.44 Pistol</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="10mm_pistol">10mm Pistol</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="assault_rifle">Assault Rifle</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Your question is too broad, you should read some tutorials and come back here when you have a more specific problem (and share your attempt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, if you apply an event listener to a parent element, all the child elements of it are also listening to that event. So you can apply a click event to the `<ul>`. So all the `<li>` items are listening to that event.
Then use a switch case to switch between different click events.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script>
    
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded' , function(){
        var list = document.getElementById('allList');
        var image = document.getElementById('targetImg');

        list.addEventListener('click' , function(e){

            switch(e.target.textContent){
                case '44 Pistol':
                    image.setAttribute("src" , "https://www.pewpewtactical.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/8.-Glock-44-.22LR.jpg");
                    break;
                case '10mm Pistol':
                    image.setAttribute("src" , "https://www.airgundepot.com/vault/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Other-Pistol-Options.jpg");
                    break;
                case 'Assault Rifle':
                    image.setAttribute("src" , "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/819LnIT7GSL._AC_SL1500_.jpg");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        })
    })
    
</script>
<body>
    <div class="tab-pane active full" id="status" role="tabpanel">
        <ul class="item-list" id="allList">
          <li><a id="pipboy_gun_img" href="#" class="44_pistol">44 Pistol</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="10mm_pistol">10mm Pistol</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="assault_rifle">Assault Rifle</a></li>
        </ul>
        <img height="400px" width="400px" id="targetImg" src="" alt="">
</body>
</html>
```

**side note**: If you wondering what is this **DOMContentLoaded**, It prevents the javascript part is being executed before the HTML DOM is loaded.
If you don't want to use it just cut and paste `<script> **your java script code ** </script>`  below the `body tag`.

Comment: Thanks so much, that's exactly what I needed!